# How does one add an assembly reference to an existing cross plateform solution in xamarin 6.0.2 studio on mac

Tags: macos, xamarin

I am trying to to get a sample cross platform application running in xamarin studio community 6.0.2 on mac OSX El Capitan. the app can be found on github [here](https://github.com/15mgm15/XamarinFormsCamera). the problem is that when I try and run the application, i get an error saying "the type or namespace 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin'. are you missing an assembly reference?" this error is occuring in the mediaPicker.cs file
I have installed the package console extension, and ran this command 
"Install-Package Xam.Plugin.Media -Version 2.3.0", but I still see this error.

Comment: that code is 2 years old - it likely does not work with the current Media plugin.  The Media Plugin has it's own Sample: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/tree/master/samples

Comment: thanks jason. I am looking into it now. i appreciate it quite a bit!

Comment: when I try and run the project, I get an error saying 

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task DetectSigningIdentity: Directory '/Users/thatDude/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles' not found. (MediaSample.iOS)
I am not sure what this error means, nor how to fix it. do I need to create the file that does not exist at the specified path? if so, what do I put in it?